# Page break inside avoid property in safari browser

Tags: css

`page-break-inside : avoid` doesn't work in print view of safari browser.

I have tried adding `page-break-inside : avoid` for content inside the table row. It breaks perfectly in chrome. but the property is not applied in safari

Is there any way that the property can work in print view in safari browser

**reference:**
the below reference url says that the safari browser supports `page-brake-inside`
[Reference url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)

Comment: @Pete if I add that then the functionality breaks in chrome.

Comment: safari only stylesheet?

Comment: it would be helpful if a common stylesheet can be provided atleast it works in safari and chrome